# filter price range with drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a problem with some code.
Im trying to create a dropdown filter that has a few options must be based on a certain price range.
I am unable to find a suitable way to add the 2 values to the price range dropdown and make it filter the way the others too.
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/myhassim/pen/gOadjQL)

```
//what i have tried

    if (prices.indexOf("<option value='" + price + "'>" + price + '</option>') == -1) {
        prices += "<option value='" + price + "'>" + price + '</option>'
    }
```

Please help out.thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is expected?

Comment: Seems to me there's a more fundamental problem with your code: keeping business logic and presentation code (UX stuff like HTML tags) separate. It' will behoove you to learn jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to find a suitable way to add the 2 values to the price range dropdown

This issue happens because you have not added the generated HTML string to the DOM for the `price`. To fix it, you simply need to do:

```
$('.filter-price').append(prices)
```

> and make it filter the way the others too.

Now the issue here is for the `product` divs you have set the `data-price` attribute value like:

```
rawPrice = price.replace('$', ''),
rawPrice = parseInt(rawPrice.replace(',', '')),

....
"' data-price='" + rawPrice
```

So, you can understand `data-price` here actually like `3000` instead of `$3,000`. But in the filter you are simply doing:

```
filters += '[data-' + key + "='" + filtersObject[key] + "']"
```

and thus the filter is not working for price range as `3000` is not equal to  `$3,000`. To fix this, you simply need to convert the `filtersObject[key]` to the same format, but only for the `price` key as:

```
for (var key in filtersObject) {
  if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (key === 'price') {
      var rawPrice = filtersObject[key].replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
      filters += '[data-' + key + "='" + rawPrice + "']"
    } else {
      filters += '[data-' + key + "='" + filtersObject[key] + "']"
    }
  }
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    make: 'Gibson',
    model: 'Les Paul',
    type: 'Electric',
    price: '$3,000',
    image: 'http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/LPST5HTHDCH-medium.jpg?9782bd'
  },
  {
    make: 'Gibson',
    model: 'SG',
    type: 'Electric',
    price: '$1,500',
    image: 'http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/SGSEBCH-medium.jpg?e69cfe'
  },
  {
    make: 'Fender',
    model: 'Telecaster',
    type: 'Electric',
    price: '$2,000',
    image: 'http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/TelePLMPHB-medium.jpg?28e48b'
  }
]

var products = '',
  makes = '',
  models = '',
  types = '',
  prices = ''

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var make = data[i].make,
    model = data[i].model,
    type = data[i].type,
    price = data[i].price,
    rawPrice = price.replace('$', ''),
    rawPrice = parseInt(rawPrice.replace(',', '')),
    image = data[i].image

  //create product cards
  products +=
    "<div class='col-sm-4 product' data-make='" +
    make +
    "' data-model='" +
    model +
    "' data-type='" +
    type +
    "' data-price='" +
    rawPrice +
    "'><div class='product-inner text-center'><img src='" +
    image +
    "'><br />Make: " +
    make +
    '<br />Model: ' +
    model +
    '<br />Type: ' +
    type +
    '<br />Price: ' +
    price +
    '</div></div>'

  //create dropdown of makes
  if (makes.indexOf("<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + '</option>') == -1) {
    makes += "<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + '</option>'
  }

  //create dropdown of models
  if (models.indexOf("<option value='" + model + "'>" + model + '</option>') == -1) {
    models += "<option value='" + model + "'>" + model + '</option>'
  }

  //create dropdown of types
  if (types.indexOf("<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + '</option>') == -1) {
    types += "<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + '</option>'
  }
  //create dropdown of prices
  if (prices.indexOf("<option value='" + price + "'>" + price + '</option>') == -1) {
    prices += "<option value='" + price + "'>" + price + '</option>'
  }
}

$('#products').html(products)
$('.filter-make').append(makes)
$('.filter-model').append(models)
$('.filter-type').append(types)
$('.filter-price').append(prices)

var filtersObject = {}

//on filter change
$('.filter').on('change', function() {
  var filterName = $(this).data('filter'),
    filterVal = $(this).val()

  if (filterVal == '') {
    delete filtersObject[filterName]
  } else {
    filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal
  }

  var filters = ''

  for (var key in filtersObject) {
    if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (key === 'price') {
        var rawPrice = filtersObject[key].replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
        filters += '[data-' + key + "='" + rawPrice + "']"
      } else {
        filters += '[data-' + key + "='" + filtersObject[key] + "']"
      }
    }
  }

  if (filters == '') {
    $('.product').show()
  } else {
    $('.product').hide()
    $('.product').hide().filter(filters).show()
  }
})

//on search form submit
$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var query = $('#search-form input').val().toLowerCase()

  $('.product').hide()
  $('.product').each(function() {
    var make = $(this).data('make').toLowerCase(),
      model = $(this).data('model').toLowerCase(),
      type = $(this).data('type').toLowerCase()

    if (make.indexOf(query) > -1 || model.indexOf(query) > -1 || type.indexOf(query) > -1) {
      $(this).show()
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.product {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-inner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 10%;
}

.product img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* navbar */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: black !important;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  color: #000 !important;
}


/* header */

.logo {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  font-family: 'Lalezar', cursive;
  color: #000;
}

.menu-icon {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  color: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.orange {
  color: #e1a917 !important;
}

.blu {
  color: rgb(49, 48, 48);
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* hero */

.hero {
  /* background: linear-gradient(#0006, #0006), url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/architect.jpg); */
  /*   background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/2600x1200?city); */
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 70vh;
  /*   background-color: #eee; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero-inner {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.hero-headline {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}


/* cards */

body {}

.prov {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49) !important;
}

.now {
  zoom: 75%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4em;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.grid>article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.grid>article img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid .text {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  padding: 5em;
  width: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.blue {
  padding: 0;
}

.ho {
  margin: 0 !important;
  margin: 0em;
}

.sm {
  font-size: x-large;
}


/* agents */


/* .moo {
 margin-top: 2em;
} */

.moos {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
}

strong {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  /* border-bottom: none; */
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  zoom: 80%;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* footer */

body {
  background: #fbfbfd;
}

.new_footer_area {
  background: #fbfbfd;
}

.new_footer_top {
  padding: 0px 0px 270px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.new_footer_area .footer_bottom {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer_bottom {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #7f88a6;
  padding: 27px 0px;
}

.new_footer_top .company_widget p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #6a7695;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.new_footer_top .company_widget .f_subscribe_two .btn_get {
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn_get_two:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #5e2ced;
}

.btn_get:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6754e2;
  border-color: #6754e2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
button:hover,
button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.new_footer_top .f_widget.about-widget .f_list li a:hover {
  color: #5e2ced;
}

.new_footer_top .f_widget.about-widget .f_list li {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.f_widget.about-widget .f_list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.f_widget.about-widget .f_list li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.f_widget.about-widget .f_list {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.new_footer_top .f_social_icon a {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 43px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2eb;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.f_social_icon a {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #858da8;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ebeef5;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.ti-facebook:before {
  content: "\e741";
}

.ti-twitter-alt:before {
  content: "\e74b";
}

.ti-vimeo-alt:before {
  content: "\e74a";
}

.ti-pinterest:before {
  content: "\e731";
}

.btn_get_two {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #5e2ced;
  border-color: #5e2ced;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn_get_two:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #5e2ced;
}

.new_footer_top .f_social_icon a:hover {
  background: #5e2ced;
  border-color: #5e2ced;
  color: white;
}

.new_footer_top .f_social_icon a+a {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.new_footer_top .f-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #263b5e;
}

.f_600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.f_size_18 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #4b505e;
}

.new_footer_top .f_widget.about-widget .f_list li a {
  color: #6a7695;
}

.new_footer_top .footer_bg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("http://droitthemes.com/html/saasland/img/seo/footer_bg.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 266px;
}

.new_footer_top .footer_bg .footer_bg_one {
  background: url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mvKUJFGEc-k/XclCOUSvCnI/AAAAAAAAUAE/jnBSf6Fe5_8tjjlKrunLBXwceSNvPcp3wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/volks.gif") no-repeat center center;
  width: 330px;
  height: 105px;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 22s linear infinite;
  animation: myfirst 22s linear infinite;
}

.new_footer_top .footer_bg .footer_bg_two {
  background: url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hjgfxUW1o1g/Xck--XOdlxI/AAAAAAAAT_4/JWYFJl83usgRFMvRfoKkSDGd--_Sv04UQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/cyclist.gif") no-repeat center center;
  width: 88px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 38%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 30s linear infinite;
  animation: myfirst 30s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    left: -25%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    left: -25%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    left: -25%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}


/*************footer End*****************/

$BorderColor: #cccccc !global;
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list--list-item {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $BorderColor;
  &:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.no-result {
  display: none;
}

.down {
  margin: 3%;
  background-color: #e1a917 !important;
  color: rgb(245, 236, 236) !important;
}


/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .down {
    margin: 2%;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .down {
    margin: 1% 1% 3% 1%;
  }
}

.up {
  width: 35vw;
  background-color: #e1a917 !important;
  color: rgb(245, 236, 236) !important;
  border: none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .up {
      width: 75vw;
    }
  }
  /* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .up {
      width: 87vw;
    }
  }
}


/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .down {
    margin: 1%;
  }
}

.block {
  background-color: #e1a917 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

.product {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-inner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 10px;
}

.product img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wou {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lalezar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="buy.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://themify.me/wp-content/themes/themify-v32/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://entrusters.com/modules/mod_entrusters_shopbyurl/css/urldata.previewer.min.csshttps://entrusters.com/modules/mod_entrusters_shopbyurl/css/urldata.previewer.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://entrusters.com/templates/yoo_moustache/css/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Buy</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <div class="row" id="search">
    <form id="search-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="padding-right: 4em;">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="filter">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <select data-filter="make" class="filter-make filter form-control">
          <option value="">Select Make</option>
          <option value="">Show All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <select data-filter="model" class="filter-model filter form-control">
          <option value="">Select Model</option>
          <option value="">Show All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <select data-filter="type" class="filter-type filter form-control">
          <option value="">Select Type</option>
          <option value="">Show All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <select data-filter="price" class="filter-price filter form-control">
          <option value="">Select Price Range</option>

          <option value="">Show All</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="products">

  </div>
</div>
```